# LiveData<String>To Float Parse Replace

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm using the Google purchase library and I'm using the price via a LiveData. Price tag: It looks like $20.99. I have to parse this data and print only 20.99. For this, I think I need to convert the LiveData String data to float or integer. How can I do that?

```
static public class SkuDetails {
    final public String sku;
    final public LiveData<String> title;
    final public LiveData<String> description;
    final public LiveData<String> price;
    final public int iconDrawableId;

    SkuDetails(@NonNull String sku, TrivialDriveRepository tdr) {
        this.sku = sku;
        title = tdr.getSkuTitle(sku);
        description = tdr.getSkuDescription(sku);
        price = tdr.getSkuPrice(sku);
        iconDrawableId = skuToResourceIdMap.get(sku);
    }
}
```

BillingClient;

```
public final LiveData<String> getSkuPrice(String sku) {
    LiveData<SkuDetails> skuDetailsLiveData = skuDetailsLiveDataMap.get(sku);
    assert skuDetailsLiveData != null;
    return Transformations.map(skuDetailsLiveData, SkuDetails::getPrice);
}
```

EDIT: Sorry, I forgot to add the line of code that prints the price information correctly. I have shared the code I need to parse below.

```
public LiveData<String> getSkuPrice(Subscription var1) {
    return getSkuDetails(var1.getSku()).price;
}
```

Activity.xml;

```
android:text="@{viewModel.getSkuPrice(subscription)}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this once you've `price` LiveData assigned.

```
// get the string value from "price" LiveData
String strPrice = price.getValue();
    
//remove dollar sign from this price
String priceWithoutDollarSign = strPrice.replaceAll("[^\\d.]", "");
    
//convert/parse it as float just in-case needed otherwise priceWithoutDollarSign will be enough
float resultPrice = Float.parseFloat(priceWithoutDollarSign);
```

Comment: It throws an error in the priceWithoutDollarSign code. 
'java.lang.String java.lang.String.replaceAll(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Comment: @HakanAktun You need to make sure that you call it after `price` live-data has value in it. If the value is null. Then `strPrice`  will throw this error.

Comment: We get the price live with getSkuPrice. I updated the topic, can you take a look?

Comment: @HakanAktun Your code seems fine to me. You just need to put my snippet once the value is assigned to the `price`. I can't seem to track when exactly is that assigned with non-null values.